# Flash Facebook Application How to do it

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, facebook

I'm experienced in database systems. This is the first time I'm developing a web site completely, either i will use firstly flash.

I do not know how I can put a flash application as a facebook application, which is working behind with a asp.net page [web services between]

If you will inform me about, i will be happy. Sorry for my hurry and being lazy, and sorry for this stupid question. I need an shorter and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following video and articles under that page's resource section.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/video_facebook_quick_start.html